# How does the frequency increase and decrease in a FM transmitter circuit?

Tags: transistors, capacitor, oscillator, frequency-modulation

i still dont understand how fm transmitter circuit works, from what i understand the transistor acts like a switch or a valve when the output voltage increases and decreases wont it affect the amplitude of the wave? And whats the use of C2?. I saw some fm signal images i dont understand how it increase and decrease the frequency by controlling the voltage!

[image]

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/259824/how-does-this-fm-transmitter-work?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

For FM modulation, it's easier to consider the two functions separately.

First there's the oscillator. Referring to your linked picture, Q1 provides the gain, and L1, VC1 and C2 provide a tapped resonant circuit that gives the transistor the right sort of feedback to oscillate. This oscillation frequency depends on the effective value of each of those components.

Then there's the frequency modulation. The resonant circuit has several extra capacitances connected to it. There's the Q1 collector-emitter capacitance connected to C2, and more importantly, the Q1 collector-base capacitance, connected to L1 via the large fixed caps C1 and C3. These transistor capacitances vary with applied voltage, which includes the audio voltage you're feeding in.

It's not a big variation, and in professional voltage controlled oscillators we usually use an extra component, a varactor, which has a larger range and a better specified control law, to modulate a VCO. However the effect is always present in transistors, and quite big enough to put audio modulation onto an FM-band oscillator for hobby use as here.

Comment: But how isit possible for the frequency to increase and decrease? Like when there is a 1hz signal comming out of the collector to the lc circuit wouldnt it change the amplitude, turning the lc circuit on and off?

Comment: @user93228 The frequency increases and decreases as the change in base voltage due to the microphone changes the transistor capacitances. The oscillation continues, with a swing of several volts, regardless of small (mV up to 10s of mV) variations of base voltage. The oscillation amplitude *does* vary slightly with base voltage, and that's a defect that would not be permitted in a professional circuit, but it doesn't stop the circuit working as an FM transmitter. An FM receiver ignores the signal amplitude variation anyway.

Comment: sorry but could you explain how the transistor work together with the lc circuit? I still dont understand how the circuit works