# Designing FM Transmitter

Tags: analog, transmitter, frequency-modulation

I am a student and I want to learn how to practically design a FM Transmitter circuit, I have this circuit here and I would be grateful if someone could tell me how to calculate and select all the components, what are the designing parameters and how to calculate them. Or if any sources that can explain me how to design it myself.

I understand that transmitting on the FM Band is illegal but I only intend to go up to 10 metres and nothing more. I'll keep the antenna very short (say an inch) and only make it longer if needed to hear the transmitter a few metres away, that's all.

Circuit - By Art Swan

https://www.instructables.com/The-Ultimate-FM-Transmitter/

[image]

Comment: note that you're learning something old-school. "Real" FM transmitters have not been build like that in a rather long time. The question really becomes what you want to learn – quite evident by your question, you're still lacking the basics of circuits, which suggest you should start with something else than something that depends on dynamic behaviour of transistors. Also note that transmitting without a license is illegal everywhere on this world, and you might be much better off *not* doing it.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Serious FM transmitters haven't ever been built like that. It's always been a hack circuit for beginners.

Comment: @GrahamNye ha! not quite what I wanted to imply – what I wanted to say is "if you want to learn how to build a serious FM transmitter, starting from a simplified version, then this will take you nowhere – not even the basic principles of modulation are relevant, nor is the way power is brought onto the antenna". Of course you right – nobody would ever have hoped to build a stable, sensible-quality, low OOB emission, transmitter with two transistor and a handul of resistors

Comment: @MarcusMüller An actually working transmitter will require a licence. I suggest an amateur radio licence which will be associated with a course that covers topics of interest to the OP.

Comment: OK folks, a rudimentary description of how to calculate everything in this circuit will fit in an answer of reasonable length. I have upvoted the question, voted to reopen it, and will answer it myself. It's not a bad question - it's very focused, has fixed scope, little in the way of leeway for opinion in an answer. It may well be that most close voters won't bother to answer it, but hey, don't measure everyone with the same stick. Some of us enjoy that sort of stuff :)

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica if you understand this question as "How would I come up with this design and then with these component choices", I agree, this is of manageable breadth. Voting to reopen. (you haven't yet, says the reopen vote count?!)

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica I'd caution that chances are a solid amount of this question being a duplicate of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/259824/how-does-this-fm-transmitter-work?rq=1 , by the way, but I know you write very nice circuit explanations, so I think you can indeed add to what Andy wrote there.

Comment: @copperwire please ask a specific question.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to EE.SE

> how to calculate and select all the components,

That's already been done for you. All component values are given in the quoted diagram.

A decoupling capacitor would be nice (between the 9 V and 0 V rails). The value isn't critical, a 1 - 10 nF ceramic capacitor would be fine.

> what are the designing parameters and how to calculate them.

A tutorial explaining the selection of all the components is rather too large a scope for a question here. You have a common emitter audio amplifier stage (Q1) feeding a common base Colpitts oscillator stage (Q2).

You can look up how to design each stage separately, using those descriptions. If you get stuck you can ask specific questions showing some research and stating what you didn't understand. Good luck with your journey into electronics.

Don't try building a 100 MHz circuit on solderless breadboard. You can build it ugly bug style on plain (unetched) pcb material or a pcb design is available via your favourite search engine.

Comment: Perhaps due to this Vermonter's disdain for black-flies and mosquitos, I prefer to call those "ugly bugs"  "**dead bugs**" instead.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-point_construction: ..."is "dead bug" style, with the ICs flipped upside-down with their pins sticking up into the air like a dead insect, the leads of components are usually soldered directly to other components where possible,"

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen Another technique is [Manhattan style](http://www.massmind.org/techref/pcb/manhattan.htm) with little offcuts of pcb stuck on to unetched pcb to make joints. The main point though is to stay away from solderless breadboard.